# PHP: issue with switch statement (wrong return)

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this method:

```
private function convertStatusStringToIntZeroOrOne(string $status)
{

    $status = strtolower($status);

    switch ($status) {

        case "off":
        case "0":
        case 0:
            $int_status = 0;
            break;

        case "on":
        case "1":
        case 1:
            $int_status = 1;
            break;

        default:
            $int_status = 1;
            break;


    }

    return $int_status;
}
```

The `$status` parameter, when is the string "On" (with O letter capitalize), return 0 (zero).

Of course, I need return as 1.

Thank you

Comment: Because you're doing a type juggle from string to int when testing for `0`. And `'on' == 0` is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you had numeric 0 and 1 in the options of the `switch` it was using a numeric comparison - "on" to a number is 0 and so it matched against 0.

As you have the parameter as type `string` a number would be converted to a string, so remove the numeric comparisons...

```
function convertStatusStringToIntZeroOrOne(string $status)
{
    $status = strtolower($status);

    switch ($status) {
        case "off":
        case "0":
            $int_status = 0;
            break;
        case "on":
        case "1":
            $int_status = 1;
            break;
        default:
            $int_status = 1;
            break;
    }

    return $int_status;
}
echo convertStatusStringToIntZeroOrOne("On");
```

Although you could reduce the function to...

```
function convertStatusStringToIntZeroOrOne(string $status)
{
    $status = strtolower($status);
    return ($status == "off" || $status == 0)?0:1;
}
```

Comment: Could be reduced even further to `return (int) ! in_array(strtolower($status), ['off', '0'], true);` - but that's less clear :-)